# How to send a variable with a addListener?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

My popup script tries to get a variable from a content script:

```
browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        //console.log("TryToCall");
        searchTerm = browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: "getDoi" });
        console.log("received message: " + searchTerm);
        setButtons(searchTerm);
    });
```

The content script listens with:

```
function listener(message, sender, response) {
    //console.log("called");
    switch (message.type) {
        case "getDoi":
            console.log("I heard you. I send " + searchTerm)
            return searchTerm ;
        default:
            //console.error("Unrecognised message: " + message);
            return "X";
    }
}
```

The problem is: Instead of the string `searchTerm` (it is defined elsewhere and is correctly set in the listener as the console prints it out correctly) my popup gets `[object Promise]`.

This is probably super simple, but I can't figure out how to make the popup to receive the string or convert the promise to the string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this where you get the promise value.

`then` is an object that launches after an promise has been resolved.
In the same way if a promise has been rejected you can use `.catch(res=>{})` to get an exception of some sort.

In this case it would be

```
 searchTerm.then((res)=>{
      return res;
 })
.then((res) => {
      console.log(res); //here is not a promise anymore, It will probably be an object that you can access
})
```

and then you will have your variable in the next then.
In addition this will probably return you a json object, but if u want it as a text you can do

```
searchTerm.then((res)=>{
      return res.path_to_string.text(); //Access the path of the res that contains the string you need and then convert it 
 })
.then((res) => {
      console.log(res); //You will have a string containing the whole object.
})
```

I suggest you doccumenting more on [Javascript Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.
Sadly, your code doesn't work for me.
For one `res` has to be defined outside the function right?
Next `res() =>` throws a syntax error. Removing the () and it just returns undefined.

I will read up on the documentation though. Thanks for the link!

Comment: My bad , I was inside the train when I've written that and I was not paying attention, res was supoosed to be the parameter of a callback function. Instead of res() put res inside the paranthesis. I've edited my awnser

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The code works now :)
I still need to figure out how the actual promise object looks like but I'll do that with documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to temporarily fix the problem:

I replaced the promise with `sendResponse`.
Whatever is send back by sendResponse is then readable via `sendResponse.value`:

```
function listener(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        switch (message.type) {
            case "getDoi":
                sendResponse ({ value: searchTerm });
            default:
                //console.error("Unrecognised message: " + message);
                sendResponse({value: "Error"});
        }    
}
```

Which is picked up by:

```
function handleResponse(message) {
    console.log("Message: " + message.value);
    setButtons(message.value);
}
function handleError(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.value);
}

    browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        browser.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { type: "getDoi" }).then(handleResponse,handleError);
    })
```

So apparently `sendResponse` is going to be phased out (? https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/16#issuecomment-296693219) and I will have to fix that at some point, but for now it works.